# Can I validate an exact value with zod?

Tags: zod

Validating a string can be done with a regex. That's easy.

```js
const myString = z.string().regex(/A string/);
```

But what about other data types?

I guess the following could work for number, but it doesn't seem idiomatic.

```js
const myNumber = z.number().gte(7).lte(7);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Zod Literals](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#literals) to match exact values. Inferred types will also be exactly the value specified rather than `number`.

For example:

```js
const myNumber = z.literal(7);
```